# How to prevent torchligh highlighter from parsing blade component

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, highlight, torchlight-laravel

For example, I have this code that I want to show it as it is in my web page:

```
<x-input-wrapper>
      <x-input label="Label" class="block w-60 mt-1" type="text"
         placeholder="{{ __('With Label') }}" />
</x-input-wrapper>
```

But using torchlight highlighter, it automatically parse the code inside the < x-input-wrapper> and < x-input>. Which is not what I want.

This question may looks simple, but I have spent quite some time in the documentation looking for the solution without result.
And is there any good alternatives for rapid code highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

just a test

```html
<pre>
        &lt;x-input-wrapper&gt;
            &lt;x-input label="Label" class="block w-60 mt-1" type="text" placeholder="{{'{{'}} {!! '__('.'With Label'.')' !!} {{"}"}}{{"}"}}" /&gt;
        &lt;/x-input-wrapper&gt;
    </pre>
```